# Why don't some widgets work on Cyanogen?

Tags: app-widgets, cyanogenmod

I have a HTC Hero CDMA that I upgraded to Cyanogen 6.  I'm on version 6.0.0-Heroc-testing2.  Before installing Cyanogen, I had the official Twitter widget and official Facebook widget on one of my screens.  Ever since upgrading, I have not been able to add the Facebook widget or Twitter Widget.  Both of the apps work fine, but when I go to the list of widgets I can add, neither of them is there.  I'm using the default home screen/launcher that comes with Cyanogen.  Other widgets such as Beautiful Widgets work just fine.

Is this a problem with Cyanogen, the home screen, or something else?  I have a hard time believing these widgets are only compatible with HTC Sense.

Comment: Are you sure that you're using the official, downloaded from the Market versions of Facebook, and Twitter? From what I remember most Sense phones come with HTC versions of Facebook pre-installed with Sense widgets (can't remember about Twitter, no one I know with an HTC uses it). Try redownloading from the Market and double-check to see if you've got multiple Facebook widgets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you download another home launcher like LauncherPro (I highly recommend it) and see if the widgets also don't work there?  It could be a problem with the launcher you are using (ADW or Launcher2).  Or you could re-flash CM6 with the other launcher than the one you chose.

If these are the official Twitter/Facebook app widgets, then I doubt it is because of HTC Sense no longer being available.

Additionally it sounds like you are running a test build of CM6, so it may be a bug.  Check out [their forums](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/) to see if anyone else has your problem or to report the issue.

Comment: Just checked and there is now a stable version of CM6 for my phone, so I'll see if that fixes it.

Comment: @Jay that might fix your problem.  You may want to do a full wipe of data/apps/cache before you upgrade to the release version.

Comment: I updated CM to the latest stable build and now it seems to work.  The problem was with the test build.

Answer (score 0):

The version the OP is running should not be a test build. 6.0 is their stable, but checking out their forums is not a bad idea.

Changing the launcher is a good troubleshooting step, but shouldn't make a difference in this case since CM ROMs do not have sense running. So if a widget works with LP it should work with the default launcher of CM and vice versa.

The OP should follow GAThrawn's advice and make sure the official widgets from the marketplace are being used. Since the OP has a Hero it is possible they might have a sense version of one of those apps installed and sense anything will not work on a CM ROM.

Comment: The testing2 part of the build version is throwing me off which why I said that :)

Comment: Ah, maybe he is using an older version of the 6.0 build. The latest 6.0 for the Hero should be a stable build.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce that. On my g1, with actual cyanogen mod 6.0 i'm able to add the facebook and also the twitter widgets (both, big and small).